# Python 3.7.3 variables with numbers in while loop conditionals

Tags: python-3.7

So I'm trying to learn some python3 with some simple code as stated below. The point of the code is to have a loop that runs until one of the files exists and contains data. For some reason i'm getting an error running this, saying that the variable has an invalid syntax just as if numbers in variables are illegal ([which they arent](https://realpython.com/python-variables/)?):

```
$ python3 test.py
  File "test.py", line 14
    While file1==False and file2==False and file3==False:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code:

```
import os

filePath1 = '/some/path'
filePath2 = '/some/path'
filePath3 = '/some/path'
file1 = False 
file2 = False
file3 = False

While file1==False and file2==False and file3==False:
    if os.path.exists(filePath1):
        with open(filePath1,'r') as f:
            try:
                file1 = f.read()
            except:
                print("No file data.")

    if os.path.exists(filePath2):
        with open(filePath2,'r') as f:
            try:
                file2 = f.read()
            except:
                print("No file data.")

    if os.path.exists(filePath3):
        with open(filePath3,'r') as f:
            try:
                file3 = f.read()
            except:
                print("No file data.")
```

I don't understand this because:

```
>>>file1=False
>>>file2=False
>>>file1==False and file2==False
True
```

I'd be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`invalid syntax` is caused by your capitalized `While` keyword, which python doesn't recognize. Use the reserved keyword `while`, small letters only.

Comment: Geez, it really was that simple... Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem, sometimes you just need fresh eyes. Good luck learning python!